# Generic class not respecting type

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
class AugmentedSet<T>{
    private set: Set<T> = new Set<T>();

    add (item: any){
        this.set.add(item)
        item._parent = this;
    }
}

class Foo{}
class Bar{}

const foo = new Foo()
const bar = new Bar();
const augSet = new AugmentedSet<Foo>();
augSet.add(foo);
augSet.add(bar); // should not work, different type
```

I'm attempting to create a class that augments the `Set` class. For various reasons not shown in this example, I don't want to extend `Set`, nor do I want to modify the literal `Set` prototype. Instead, I simply want to create a Set-like object that is typed.

What I expect to happen is typescript allowing only Foo classes to be added via `AugmentedSet.add()`, however it seems to allow both Foo and Bar.

I am probably not understanding how to properly type this class / methods, so I'm looking for any guidance here. :)

Comment: You declared `add` to take `any`, so it takes any object. If you want it to take `T`, declare its argument to be of type `T`.

Comment: Why do you need `item._parent = this`?

Comment: As for purposes of `item._parent = this`, this is a way to set the items container to the Augmented set, so that if we need to get to the set itself from the item, we can do so. I have a much more complicated example (python code that I'm trying to port over) that uses similar kinds of patterns, and this was just a quick and simple way to demoing purposes. Changing it to `item: T` makes this parent property assignment fail as `T` doesn't know about `_parent` :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Foo` and `Bar` are assignable to each other in your example because of structural typing, and they have the same set of properties. You can try it:

```
let foo: Foo = new Bar() ; // will typecheck
```

This is the reason your `Set<Foo>` accepts `Bar`s too. Just add some differing methods to your Foo and Bar classes and will get the expected behavior.

*Edit* @Silvio in the comments noticed something I didn't, that's another, more direct reason. Must consider both to get the expected behavior.

Comment: Just to add something, since this is just for debugging / learning purposes, one really easy way to make two classes not assignable to each other is to give each a private field. Private fields (even if they share a name) are not the same across different classes.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a little more sense, however when making `item: T`, i'm not able to do `item._parent = this;` ecause it doesn't exist on type T. Would this be a situation in which a `T extends X` would be useful, and have it extend a class that is known to contain these properties?

Comment: Simply don't set `item._parent = this`. Noone expect that adding an object into a collection to mutate it. There must be another solution to your problem using maps or symbols.